# Check Shared Facebook Post <Social.framework> privacy settings - Audience

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, social-framework

I allow users to share photos of their game play to Facebook for a reward and I am wondering how I can check what privacy settings they use? Currently I use Social.h `SLServiceTypeFacebook` and they can share the photo and I get feedback in the app and reward them for sharing. Unfortunately on the pop-up "share" screen users can change the audience to "Only Me" and then they haven't *really* shared, but I don't know this and I still reward them with in-game credits. How can I detect if they've set the privacy settings "audience" to "Only me" using the Social.framework?